# Are there known examples like this almost official exposition of ZFC that is very weak?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, foundations, axioms

**Pseudo-ZFC** is a theory written in the usual language of set theory, i.e. mono-sorted first order logic with equality and membership. The extra-logical axioms are:

1. **Extensionality:** $\forall x \forall y: \forall z (z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y) \to x=y$
2. **Emptyset:** $\exists x: x=\varnothing$
3. **Foundation:** $\forall x: x \neq \varnothing \to \exists y \in x \, (y \cap x = \varnothing)$
4. **Pairing:** $\forall a \forall b \exists x: a \in x \land b \in x$
5. **Union:** $\forall a \exists x \forall y \forall z: z \in y \in a \to z \in x$
6. **Power set:** $\forall a \exists x \forall y: y \subseteq a \to y \in x$
7. **Collection:** $\forall a \exists b: \forall x \in a [\exists y \, (\varphi(x,y)) \to   \exists y \in b: \varphi(x,y)]$; if $b$ doesn't occur free in formula $\varphi$
8. **Infinity**: $\exists x: \varnothing \in x \land \forall y \in x \exists z \in x: z=\{y\}$
9. **Separation'**: $\forall a: a \not \in a \to \exists x: x=\{y \in a \mid \varphi\}$, if $x$ doesn't occur free in formula $\varphi$.
10. **Choice:** $\forall x: (  \forall a \in x \forall b \in x: a \neq b \to a \cap b=\varnothing) \to \\ \exists y: \forall z \in x \, (z \neq \varnothing \to  \exists! u: u \in z \land u \in y)$

Note: the symbols $\varnothing$, $\cap$, $\{ \mid \}$, and $\{\cdot\}$ are defined symbols and carry their usual meaning.

This is almost an official exposition of $\sf ZFC$, the only difference is in Separation, which is taken to operate only on non-self membered sets, which at first glance just appear to be a quite harmless tweak. However, Pseudo-ZFC is extremely weak, much weaker than Peano or even Robinson's arithmetic.

Such phenomena must have been extensively explored before. Hence, my question on a source where seemingly innocent tweaks results in deleterious almost catastrophic weakening of the modified system.

Comment: Why does this version of separation make the system so weak? This is not obvious.

Comment: What does "official exposition" mean?

Comment: @LSpice, it means the usually presented exposition regarding the language, the axioms, etc.. All axioms given here are the usual ones or lets say known and used versions of the usual ones with the exception of the minimal modification of posing a conditioning on Separation. Such a minor modification but with deleterious impact!

Comment: @JoshuaZ, well that's the fun of it. The whole point is that it is not obvious, but still not that difficult to figure out, it is more of a subtlety. But something that one may not notice at first glance.

Comment: @LSpice, as an example see the [Wikipedia source on ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#Axioms). Although the Wikipedia is not official, but yet the same you'll see at other sources. The implicational versions of the axioms other than separation is well known and customarily used by many sources.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1210999), I did not mean to doubt its near-faithfulness to the usual axiomatisation; I was just confused by the wording (for example, I am more used to speaking of "the usual" than of "an official" presentation of a mathematical concept) and thought that you might be using some technical terminology.

Comment: The axiom of infinity implies that $\{\varnothing\}$ and $\{\{\varnothing\}\}$ etc. exist, but I guess you can't prove that $\{x\}$ exists for every $x$, is that right?

Comment: For a stronger but still very weak set theory, you could add the axiom $\exists x\forall y(y\in x)$. Then the axioms of Emptyset, Pairing, Powerset, Union, and Collection become redundant.

Comment: @bof "I guess you can't prove that $\{x\}$ exists for every $x$, is that right?" - Use pairing to prove existence of a set $w$ which is a superset of $\{x,x\}$, then let $\varphi$ be the formula $y=x$ with free variables $y$ and $x$, and apply Separation' to $w$. (The variable $x$ as it is written in in Separation' is not free in $\varphi$, the variable $x$ free in $\varphi$ here is a different variable, whose value is the set whose singleton you want to prove exists.)

Comment: @bof, the question is about known examples similar to the situation here. I've hidden the reason for weakness because it is nice to see for oneself. Now, take the ambient theory of models to be a suitable version of ZFC minus Regularity, for example Aczel's, then the set $\mathcal V = \{x \mid \operatorname {Zermelo natural}(x) \lor x=\mathcal V\}$ is a model of this theory. Which is drastically weak by comparison. Now, are there famous similar examples.  For example the effect withdrawing Extensionality has on ZF would be an example but of course much less trivial . What others..?

Comment: @C7X, bof is right! There is no guarantee in this theory that the set assured to exist in the axioms is not an element of itself. This would strangulate Separation. That's the trick. A simple modification that nearly kills everything!

Comment: @bof, the reason I didn't add existence of a universal set, is that I want the theory to be a fragment of ZFC, which actually looks as if it is ZFC itself. What I'd call pseudo-theories, or pseudo-axiomatics. which are versions that supply the appearance of being an alternative axiomatization of a theory only to turn to be very weak by comparison and sometimes due to trivial reasons. Is there a discipline that deals with such pseudo-axiomatics.